# Prevent Ajax load for some page in framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

I'm looking for a way to prevent page ajax page loading for some page when clicking on link using framework7, I need to click on like then do some logic then load page using javascript after processing.
I tried the following

```
<a href="pages/restaurant-details.html" class="restaurant-grid-item" data-index="0">
```

Then in javascript

```
$(document).on('click','.restaurant-grid-item',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //Do Some Logic
     mainView.router.loadPage("pages/restaurant-details.html");
}
```

Comment: By default F7 will try to load any links with Ajax, unless specified. There a couple of ways you could do override that behavior though. Here's one way: `<a href="pages/restaurant-details.html" class="restaurant-grid-item" data-index="0">`. Check [this](http://framework7.io/docs/router-api.html) link for more details.